# ajax failing only in IE

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

i have this jquery code

```
$("#ProfileBtn").click(function () {
    if (true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sMaster.Master/outClick",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("~");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("!");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

that calls the asp.net function:

```
[ScriptMethod, WebMethod]
public static void outClick()
{

}
```

when i try it using chrome or firefox everything is fine (alert("~")), but on Internet Explorer it fails (alert("!")).

any idea why..?

**update**: i've tried putting this instead of the error:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR);
    alert(textStatus);
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

and what i get in the alerts is:

[object XMLHttpRequest]
error
undefined

i've also tried jqXHR.Status and it gave me 404 in the alert.

Comment: Alert what is the error and update in the question.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the HTTP calls in Fiddler to see if there's any differences between the calls made by the different browsers?

Comment: It would be great if you put parameters in the error handler and find out what specific error you are getting : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: vtortola and Praveen are correct, please add details about the error to your question. It could be a parsing error, because your response is zero length, but it could be something completely different. Knowing the specific error that's being caught would  make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: @vtortola i have updated the question, is that what you ment?

Comment: @Enrico is the update helping..?

Comment: 404 would indicate that IE and Opera aren't able to find the page at `sMaster.Master/outClick`... Is that supposed to be a relative URL?

Comment: @Enrico
 sMaster.Master is the page the jquery code is in, outClick (as it is in the question) is placed in sMaster.Master.cs

Comment: `sMaster.Master.cs`? I suspect IE and Opera are interpreting the url differently than the other browsers. Does using the absolute URL (incl http) work?

Comment: @Enrico um.. how will the url look like..? i'm just running it from visual studio (i don't really know what do you meen i should do =] ). i meen, the url is something like http://localhost:2388/ , and the master page doesn't have it's own URL

Comment: I've never used VS for webdev, so I'm not sure how URLs are handled. But you want something like `http://localhost:8000/outClick`, `http://sMaster.Master.cs/outClick` or `http://sMaster.Master/outClick`. Whichever works (calls your function) when you type it into the address bar in IE and Opera.

Comment: @Enrico no, it doesn't do anything. i also tried doing this with other functions in aspx pages that i know are working but the only thing it did was making most of the images disappear

Comment: I don't think I can solve your problem based on the information you've provided. There is obviously something particular to your setup that isn't easily reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood the problem is that ajax (maybe only in IE) can't call functions from master page. (I tried moving the jQuery and asp.net function to an aspx and aspx.cs page and it all worked)

Thought I did also find a better way to do what I intended.

Thanks anyway.